# C# Console App ignore Writeline output From void method while running specific arguments into main string?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-2.0

i have this code.
how can i ignore output from void method for some time while running my code?

This continue print time for each seconds. With 1 sec loop
But i want to avoid its print for specific Main string arguments are running.
i want to keep running timer as it is.
Just dont want to print writeline for Console.WriteLine("1st") from "private static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)"

```
using System;
using System.Timers;
using threadTimer = System.Threading;

namespace TimerExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static Timer timer = new Timer(1000);
        static int i = 0;


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {     
            
  
timer.Elapsed+=timer_Elapsed;
            timer.Start(); 
       Console.WriteLine("1st");
            
            
             threadTimer.Thread.Sleep (10000);  
             Console.Clear ();
             Console.Clear ();
           Console.WriteLine("2nd");
           threadTimer.Thread.Sleep (3000);  
            
        }

        private static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            float TimeToMissionsReady =  i++;
            TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimeToMissionsReady);
            string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00 Minutes} and {1:00 Seconds}",
            ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds);
            Console.Write("\r   Time Passed:  " + elapsedTime);
        }
        
        

        
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can declare a Field in program class and fill it in main method by args and check it in your timer if like this:

```
namespace TimerExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static string[] Args;
        static Timer timer = new Timer(1000);
        static int i = 0;


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {     
         Args = args;   
  
         timer.Elapsed+=timer_Elapsed;
         timer.Start(); 
         Console.WriteLine("1st");
            
            
         threadTimer.Thread.Sleep (10000);  
         Console.Clear ();
         Console.Clear ();
         Console.WriteLine("2nd");
           threadTimer.Thread.Sleep (3000);  
            
        }

        private static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            float TimeToMissionsReady =  i++;
            TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimeToMissionsReady);
            string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00 Minutes} and {1:00 Seconds}",
            ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds);
            if(!Check(Args))
                 Console.Write("\r   Time Passed:  " + elapsedTime);
        }

        private static bool Check(string[] args) 
        { 
            foreach (var arg in args) { 
                if(arg == "YourArg") 
                    return true; 
                } 
                return false; 
        }
               
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro. im getting following error..  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'TimerExample.Program.Args' . What is im missing?

Comment: Example : i just want to skip writing  void output  while i can see 1st on console. Then resume void output printed on console while i can see 2nd

Comment: @haseakash2010 I fixed my code. `Args` variable should be static. Let me know if there is any other problem.

Comment: using System.Linq; i cannot use this bcoz im using .net 2.0 . Any other solution for this code? im very glad by ur response . Thank you so much man !

Comment: you can you a method to check the `Args` parameters and check if its equal to "YourArg".
public bool Check(string[] args)
{
foreach (var arg in args)
{
if(arg == "YourArg")
retrun true;
}
return false;
}

Comment: I Fixed my solution.

Comment: retrun true ;     Error CS1002: ; expected
Build failed.  Can u please use sharpdevlope program and clear all fixes? big thanks again @علی-یا-علی